# Can I use sync_to_async for any function in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous

Background:
I'm working on a Discord bot that uses requests. The requests are asynchronous, so I'm using the library *asgiref.sync*.

(I know I obviously can't use this function for asynchronous functions.)

I implemented *sync_to_async* into all the requests and things that may take long to process. The function doesn't produce any error. However, I'm not sure if this actually does anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use sync_to_async for any function in Python?

Yes, but...

> does this mean I can convert any function to async to make things run faster and more cohesively (...)?

No. Here's a code example:

```py
import asyncio
import time

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync, sync_to_async


def sleep(t0):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(time.time() - t0)


async def async_sleep(t0):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(time.time() - t0)


sync_to_async_sleep = sync_to_async(sleep)
async_to_sync_sleep = async_to_sync(async_sleep)


async def async_main():
    print('sync')
    t0 = time.time()
    sleep(t0)
    sleep(t0)

    print('\nsync_to_async')
    t0 = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(
        sync_to_async_sleep(t0),
        sync_to_async_sleep(t0),
    )

    print('\nasync')
    t0 = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(
        async_sleep(t0),
        async_sleep(t0),
    )


def main():
    print('\nasync_to_sync')
    t0 = time.time()
    async_to_sync_sleep(t0)
    async_to_sync_sleep(t0)


asyncio.run(async_main())
main()
```

Output:

```
sync
1.00
2.01

sync_to_async
1.00
2.01

async
1.00
1.00

async_to_sync
1.00
2.01
```

Evidently, only the "async" case (true async implementation in async context) runs concurrently.

Comment: Just to flag (as per my answer below) that this happens because "`sync_to_async` will run all synchronous code in the program in the same thread for safety reasons" by default, but you *can* get parallel execution by using the `thread_sensitive=False` flag

Answer (score 2):

Async does not magically make your program runs in parallel. Within an async function there needs to be certain points where the function "gives up control", like when waiting for a response from a  remote server.

If the function you 'converted' to async either (1) CPU-bound or (2) not giving up control by invoking an `await` statement somewhere, or (3) both, then the function will run until completion until it finishes.

To put it in another way: **async is cooperative multitasking**. Async functions must, at certain points "hands over" control to the async loop to enable others to run.

Comment: I understand the part about cooperative multitasking and things, but does this mean I can convert any function to async to make things run faster and more cohesively in something like a discord bot (Where the bot needs to handle multiple requests close together as quickly as possible)?

Comment: @BlueRobin as I explicitly said, cooperative multitasking means that the async function must, within its code, "give up" control to the async event loop through `await` statements within it. A sync function convered willy-nilly into an async function will likely not have any `await` statement. Meaning that it will have exclusive control of CPU until it finishes, blocking other async tasks. Meaning that each request is handled one-by-one until completion.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it's a bit difficult to know whether you're getting any benefit or what you could be doing better.

However, you *can* use `sync_to_async` to execute synchronous functions concurrently on different threads, but you have to pass `thread_sensitive=False`. So to rework [aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74927790/5920499) with just the `sync_to_async` bit:

```py
import asyncio
import time

from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


@sync_to_async(thread_sensitive=False)
def async_sleep(t0):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(time.time() - t0)


async def async_main():
    t0 = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(
        async_sleep(t0),
        async_sleep(t0),
    )


asyncio.run(async_main())
```

Output:

```
1.0007977485656738
1.0009398460388184
```

But be careful, as per the [asgiref readme](https://github.com/django/asgiref#function-wrappers):

> Note that exactly what threads things run in is very specific [...snip...] By default, **sync_to_async will run all synchronous code in the program in the same thread** for safety reasons; **you can disable this ... with `@sync_to_async(thread_sensitive=False)`**, but make sure that your code does not rely on anything bound to threads (like database connections) when you do.

(Emphasis mine.)

So in @aaron's example the reason it didn't work is because the two synchronous functions were being run one after another on the same thread. To get concurrency you just add `thread_sensitive=False` and now the two synchronous function calls are run on separate threads in parallel (or at least as parallel as the GIL allows), but now the onus is on you to make sure that they can cope with being run in parallel and don't stamp on each other.

You may also wonder what the point is of `sync_to_async` without `thread_sensitive=False` set. Well in this example there is none, because the synchronous function is being dispatched multiple times and the hope was that they would run concurrently, which they don't. But it does allow you to run a single synchronous function in parallel with asynchronous functions, like this:

```py
import asyncio
import time

from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


@sync_to_async
def async_sleep(t0):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(time.time() - t0)


async def real_async_sleep(t0):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print(time.time() - t0)


async def async_main():
    t0 = time.time()
    await asyncio.gather(
        async_sleep(t0),
        real_async_sleep(t0),
    )


asyncio.run(async_main())
```

Output:

```
1.0015418529510498
1.0017149448394775
```