# Pythonic way to process a synchronous event (callback) in an async environment

Tags: python, async-await, python-socketio

I'm looking for a solution with which I could use the Python socketIO `disconnect` event and forward this into a fully asynchronous host class.

```
    @self._sio.event
    def disconnect():
        ''' Platform disconnected '''
        logging.info("disconnected")
        self._delegate.signaling_client_left()
```

`self._delegate.signaling_client_left()` points to a non-async function. How could I make this an async function? I tried with `asyncio.run()`, but this leads to `asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`

Comment: e.g. with `asgiref`'s `sync_to_async`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74911643/can-i-use-sync-to-async-for-any-function-in-python

Comment: Was trying your approach. Gives "RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.". The thing is: I cannot await the function directly in this callback, since it is not async

Comment: `sync_to_async`, not `async_to_sync`.

Comment: You cannot call an async function from a sync function, that is how the async subsystem in Python was designed. If you need to work with asynchronous functions, then you should use the async interfaces in python-socketio.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to solve this by making the formerly synchronous part acting asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
@self._sio.event
        def disconnect():
            ''' Platform disconnected '''
            logging.info("disconnected")
            
            async def fire():
                self._delegate.signaling_client_left()
            asyncio.create_task(fire())
```

Comment: Hmm. not really...:(